# I am writing a paper based on a clinical case previously written from two authors with whom I used to work with. Should I add them as co-author?

Tags: authorship

I am writing a paper on a rare clinical case, previously published by two authors, that in the past years used to work in the hospital in which I work now. In my paper, the case is discussed from a totally different perspective, so it will result in a different work from the previous just with the same image. I asked and obtained from the first journal permission to reprint since the journal now holds the copyright. Should I add as co-authors these two researchers?

Comment: It isn't at all clear what overlap in material there will be between the two papers and it is difficult to see what contribution the previous authors are making.  In most fields what you suggest would be dealt with by writing a comment/letter to the editor about the existing paper rather than reproducing (part of) it.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial There will be no overlap. It is a rare clinical case, they published the case as a rare finding. My paper is about the medical and surgical treatment and the follow-up of the patient at 5 years.

Comment: @Heart in that case it is not clear why any reprinting is necessary, in other fields this would normally just be a follow up paper that refers to the previous one or a comment paper.  However different fields have different approaches.  If it is reproducing a diagram or image from the previous paper, then the publisher's permission is all that is required and a reference to the original paper as the source in the caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are now better criteria for who should be a co-author or not. You should consult the ones relevant to your discipline. They are usually laid out as statements by professional organizations or by institutions. Here is one by Harvard medical school: https://hms.harvard.edu/sites/default/files/assets/Sites/Ombuds/files/AUTHORSHIP%20GUIDELINES.pdf

Most guidelines will insist on direct contributions and full responsibilities of co-authors so that your colleagues would not qualify. In reality, many people still follow looser rules, but as long as there is no direct intellectual contribution to the current paper, as seems to be the case here, no authorship should be given. While your paper is probably going to be quite terse, you should still mention by name the two authors of the other study and not just cite them, so that a reader clearly understands that you are talking about the same case and how the approaches differ.

In the future and in a similar case, you might want to consider inviting them or at least informing them at an early stage. Conflicts over authorship are avoided best by timely communication. Even if you follow published criteria, you might still get some negative reaction.